# .htaccess dynamic URL rewriting with PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a URL like this

```
www.example.com/module.php?action=do
```

I would like to have final URL like this :

```
www.exemple.com/module/do.html
```

now with .htaccess I have this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/module/(.*)\.html$ action.php?action=$1 [L]
```

But I have a 404 Error not found.
But I can't figure out what is wrong on my systax.

Comment: does `action.php` exist?

Comment: Yes it is a script

Comment: Change it to `RewriteRuke ^module/....`. htaccess does not receive leading  `/`

Comment: Ok, this works now. Thanks @hjpotter92